# Bash: How to test for failure of mkdir command?

Tags: bash, unit-testing, exit-code

I'm writing a bash script and want to do robust error checking in it.

The exit status code for `mv` to make it fail is easy to simulate a failure.  All you have to do is move a file that doesn't exist, and it fails.

However with `mkdir` I want to simulate it failing.  mkdir could fail for any number of reasons, problems with the disk, or lack of permissions, but not sure how to simulate a failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mkdir will fail if the directory already exists (unless you are using -p), and return an error code of `1` (on my system), so create the directory first to test this on your own system.  (Although I would assume that is standard across all shells.)

Alternatively, make the parent directory read-only.

Answer (score 13):

Just use

```
mkdir your_directory/
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "fatal"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

where `$?` stands for the exit code from the last command executed.

To create parent directories, when these don't exist, run `mkdir -p parent_directory/your_directory/`

Answer (score 7):

```
if ! mkdir your_directory 2>/dev/null; then
    print_error
    exit
fi
```

or

```
mkdir your_directory 2>/dev/null || { print_error; exit; }
```

Answer (score 3):

in your script , you could also put a check for the new dir ....

```
mkdir -p new_dir ;

if [ -d new_dir ]
  cd new_dir && ...... anything else you want .
else 
  echo "error in directory creation ";
  exit 2 ;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are lazy a simple `set -e` in the beginning of you script is enough. Often you just want to print an error and then terminate if something goes wrong.

Not exactly what you asked for, but perhaps what you want.